# PHP/WSDL/SOAP: Error passing parameters

Tags: php, soap, parameters, wsdl

I'm using a local WSDL to make service calls.  I'm fine passing/retrieving data when one parameter is expected by the service method(s), but when the method expects 2 or more parameters it errors out.  Ironically, when I attempt to pass 2 or more parameters it says that it only expects 1.  The method establishIdentity expects 2 parameters (processId=string & identityAttributes = object made up of the properties found in the code below.) I've include the errors for passing 1 and 2 parameters.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
require_once('nusoap.php');
require_once('BenefitSOAP.php');

$client = new SoapClient('C:\wsdl\BenefitDeterminationProcess_BenefitDialogueServiceSOAP.wsdl', array('trace' => 1));

$procID = (array)$client->start(array("prefix"=>""));

$newStringID = implode(null, $procID); //

$exchange = $client->exchangeOptions($procID);

$identityAttributes = new IdentityAttributes();
$identityAttributes->ssn = 41441414;
$identityAttributes->firstName = 'John2';
$identityAttributes->lastName = 'Doe2';
$identityAttributes->gender = 'MALE';
$identityAttributes->birthDate = NULL;    

echo "TYPE: ".gettype($newStringID);
echo "NS: ".$newStringID;

$identity = $client->establishIdentity($newStringID); //LINE 33 

//$identity = $client->establishIdentity($newStringID, $identityAttributes); OR LINE 33//establishIdentity expects 2 parameters (processId = string, identityAttributes = object)

$end = $client->stop($procID);
?>
```

Error when passing 1 parameter:

> TYPE: stringNS: 223205
>
> > Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault
> >     exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http
> >     headers in
> >     C:\wamp\www\SugarCE\testSOAPShawn.php:33
> >     Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
> >     SoapClient->_*doRequest('*_call('establishIdenti...',
> >     Array) #2
> >     C:\wamp\www\SugarCE\testSOAPShawn.php(33):
> >     SoapClient->establishIdentity('223205')> > #3 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\SugarCE\testSOAPShawn.php
> >     on line 33

Error when passing 2 parameters:

> TYPE: stringNS: 237506
>
> Fatal error:
>   Uncaught SoapFault exception:
>   [soapenv:Server]
>   javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException:
>   com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceRuntimeException:
>   An error occurred while parsing native
>   data: The error message is:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Mismatched parameter count: expecting
>   1 items, but got more.. Caused By:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Mismatched parameter count: expecting
>   1 items, but got more.: caused by: An
>   error occurred while parsing native
>   data: The error message is:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Mismatched parameter count: expecting
>   1 items, but got more.. Caused By:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Mismatched parameter count: expecting
>   1 items, but got more. in
>   C:\wamp\www\SugarCE\testSOAPShawn.php:33
>   Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
>   SoapClient->__call('establishIdenti...',
>   Array) #1
>   C:\wamp\www\SugarCE\testSOAPShawn.php(33):
>   SoapClient->establishIdentity('237506',
>   Object(IdentityAttributes)) #2 {main}
>   thrown in
>   C:\wamp\www\SugarCE\testSOAPShawn.php
>   on line 33

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your WSDL as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered:  Since the WSDL contained a complexType, I needed to pass one parameter which contained both the processId and identityAttributes.  Here is my PHP code:

```
$identityAttributes = new IdentityAttributes();
$identityAttributes->ssn = 41441414;
$identityAttributes->firstName = 'John2';
$identityAttributes->lastName = 'Doe2';
$identityAttributes->gender = 'MALE';
$identityAttributes->birthDate = NULL;

$temp = new stdClass();
$temp->processId = $newStringID;
$temp->identityAttributes = $identityAttributes;


echo "TYPE: ".gettype($newStringID);
echo "NS: ".$newStringID;

$identity = $client->establishIdentity($temp);

var_dump($identity);


$end = $client->stop($procID);
```